# Avatar always appears as undefined when used in FormData in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to create a form in which I sumbit text inputs and a file input all together and everything was working fine until I decided to implement said file input.

This is my code:

```
const [producerData, setProducerData] = useState({
    title: '',
    text: '',
    address: '',
    status: '',
    avatar: '',
});

const { title, text, address, status, avatar } = producerData;

const [avatarname, setAvatarName] = useState('Choose Avatar');
const [uploadPercentage, setUploaderPercentage] = useState(0);

const handleChange = name => e => {
    setProducerData({...producerData, [name]: e.target.value });
    // setAvatar(e.target.files[0]);
    name === 'avatar' && setProducerData({...producerData, avatar: e.target.files[0]}) && setAvatarName(e.target.files[0].name);
    // console.log(e.target.files);
}

const addProducer = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    producerData.avatar = formData.append('avatar', avatar);

    console.log(producerData);
    // addProducer(producerData, setUploaderPercentage);
}
```

Let's put it this way, it works if I create a function, maybe `setAvatar` as commented in the code. That works but when I try to use it in the same object as producerData it always returns undefined.

**EDIT**: I found out on several StackOverflow threads that in order to handle regular and file inputs together I need to do something like this:

```
const addProducer = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append( 'title', e.target.title.value)
    formData.append( 'text', e.target.text.value)
    formData.append( 'address', e.target.address.value)
    formData.append( 'status', e.target.status.value)
    formData.append('avatar', e.target.avatar.files[0]);
    console.log(formData);
    // setAvatarName(e.target.files[0].name);
    // addProducer(producerData, setUploaderPercentage);
}
```

and that I need to remove the onChange and value attributes from my inputs. 
Basically from this:

```
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Label htmlFor={`title`}>Title</Form.Label>
    <InputGroup>
        <InputGroup.Prepend>
            <InputGroup.Text id={`title-text`}>
                <i className={`fas fa-heading`} />
            </InputGroup.Text>
        </InputGroup.Prepend>
        <Form.Control
            type={`text`}
            placeholder={`Title`}
            aria-label={`title`}
            aria-describedby={`title-text`}
            autoComplete={`title`}
            name={`title`}
            id={`title`}
            required
            onChange={handleChange('title')}
            value={title}
        />
    </InputGroup>
</Form.Group>
```

to this:

```
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Label htmlFor={`title`}>Title</Form.Label>
    <InputGroup>
        <InputGroup.Prepend>
            <InputGroup.Text id={`title-text`}>
                <i className={`fas fa-heading`} />
            </InputGroup.Text>
        </InputGroup.Prepend>
        <Form.Control
            type={`text`}
            placeholder={`Title`}
            aria-label={`title`}
            aria-describedby={`title-text`}
            autoComplete={`title`}
            name={`title`}
            id={`title`}
            required
        />
    </InputGroup>
</Form.Group>
```

That's just an example of how I have the rest of the inputs that I'm working with.
Hopefully I could make myself understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what I know is that whenever you are using `useState()` hook you will be provided with `[variable , setVariable]` instead of the state in the state-full components 'classes' and the aim of `setVaraiable()`function is to control the value of your variable, so I guess you are not allowed access set the value using `producerData.avatar`.

Answer (score -2):

Set producerData same way as you do in handleChange method.

Comment: What do you mean? Also please check my updated question, I'm totally moving from state to DOM directly. Thanks.